# Concat two strings via for loop in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have one dropdown list in which in intent to show product code and product description in HTML select tag options attribute. I get the list from server then assign that list to JSON array and wrote the codes to concat two strings, concatenation  is successfull but then too i get error of 'cannot read property of 'plantCode' of undefined'.

This is my code.

```
CRService.getManufacturingPlant().success(function (data) {
    $scope.temp = [];
    $scope.temp = data.items;
    for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.temp.length; i++) {
        $scope.temp[i].customdescription = $scope.temp[i].plantCode + ' - ' + $scope.temp[i].plantDescription;
        console.log($scope.temp[i])
       }
});
```

I get output like this.

```
customdescription: "1241 - SUJAL DYE CHEM PVT. LTD."
id: 70
plantCode: "1241"
plantDescription: "SUJAL DYE CHEM PVT. LTD."
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'plantCode' of undefined
at requisitionCtrls.js:301
at angular-1.2.9.js:7578
at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular-1.2.9.js:10949)
at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular-1.2.9.js:10949)
at angular-1.2.9.js:11035
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular-1.2.9.js:11955)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular-1.2.9.js:11781)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular-1.2.9.js:12061)
at done (angular-1.2.9.js:7843)
at completeRequest (angular-1.2.9.js:8026)
```

CustomDescription is what i intent to get and show in dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issues is in for loop you go with your iteration to i=$scope.temp.length. this will generate and error since the vector is 0 based the code should work:

```
CRService.getManufacturingPlant().success(function (data) {
    $scope.temp = [];
    $scope.temp = data.items;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.temp.length; i++) {
        $scope.temp[i].customdescription = $scope.temp[i].plantCode + ' - ' + $scope.temp[i].plantDescription;
        console.log($scope.temp[i])
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop should be like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.temp.length; i++) {
```

Loop while `i` is smaller than $`scope.temp.length`, array starts from 0 zero index.